# SQL Server drop query request

Tags: sql, sql-server

It is possible to view and analyze queries in SQL Server before implement on database and log or drop it if necessary?

For example some application send an update query to SQL Server, can I first log it to a database, and then possibly reject it if the query is illegal based on my roles?

Comment: This sounds like you just need to set up the permissions correctly.

Comment: @Larnu how to log and check custom roles by permission?

Comment: That completely depends on your set up Phonix. Are you using permissions set in SQL Server, permissions set in your application, what? There's not enough information here for anyone to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Depending upon your version, edition, and _real_ requirements (there's always more to the story than what's presented), look into row-level security, SQL Audit, and DML triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to use SQL SERVER triggers so after insert or update I check my role so if there is any access problem I can rollback transaction and send error to user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Profiler to monitor queries sent to server, but you can't do what you wnat to.

If you say it is illegal for smoe roles to execute some queries it should be specified in permissions - every role have assigned permissions.

One way to achieve what you want is to define user, which mentioned applciation would use (I would even create dedicated user). Then, if you want this user to execute `SELECT`, just execute such command

```
GRANT SELECT ON [table] TO [user]
```

Then the `user` won't be able to update `table`, just select rows from it.

Comment: in my scenario user can update but can not update if city of row is not in  her/his responsibility so db reject that update.I don not have software source to hard code this role.

Comment: @Phonix, perhaps a table trigger can address your need. The trigger could rollback changes per your rules.

Comment: @DanGuzman Additionally, OP could grab user data, which executed the statement and based on that could rollback.